How to suppress warnings of MongoDB shell?
I want to parse by jq output of
mongo --quiet --eval "JSON.stringify(db.adminCommand('listDatabases'))"

But it returns
WARNING: slaveOk() is deprecated and may be removed in the next major release. Please use secondaryOk() instead.

at the start of output.
How to get ONLY JSON output and parse it with no any butthurt?

Check if the warning output is piped through stderr/file descriptor 2. You can check this by ending the command with 2>/dev/null which pipes file descriptor 2 to /dev/null and thereby throws it away.
If so, you can just pipe the command directly to jq:
mongo --quiet --eval "JSON.stringify(db.adminCommand('listDatabases'))" | jq

And you can also throw away the warning as described above if you please:
mongo --quiet --eval "JSON.stringify(db.adminCommand('listDatabases'))" 2>/dev/null | jq


No, it's not cause I previously verse grep it trough Linux utils.
But I don't want to use grep and make script messy.

@palmasd1 Update your questions with what you actually do through the Linux utils. We cannot guess what you are doing

@palmasd1 If you don't want to parse the output and it is not a part of stderr you will have to move on to the non-deprecated version.

I would move on but it's not my own infrastructure, and there're a lot of other implementations where'd be different versions of service. So the other way to suppress warning is only reverse grepping :c
